# Since the changes on 21st Feb 2018, is it possible to add a link to my website from my YouTube video?

Tags: youtube

I'd like to add an overlay of some kind to my videos, so people can directly click through to my website if they wish.

But all the tutorials I've found on how to do this, with annotations, cards, etc seem to be out of date - even ones from only December last year.
When I try to add a card, the 'link' option is disabled until I become part of the YouTube partner program, but I can't become part of that without 1000 subscribers and 4000 watch hours in the last 12 months. Neither of which I'm close to.

I don't want to make money from my videos, I only want to link to my own website. Can anyone tell me if that's possible now, and if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

You sort of answered your own question: You need to be in the YPP in order to link to external sites as of now.

That said, YouTube said they want to re-think the restrictions to certain features. So it may be that in the coming months you will be able to use it again.

Answer (score 0):

The overlays will no longer work starting January 2019.

> Update: We will stop showing existing annotations to viewers starting January 15, 2019. All existing annotations will be removed.

[Source](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/7342737).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't meet the requirement and don't think you will a good compromise could be whenever you would insert the link but can't just say or put the text that there is a link in the description of the video to your website.